# ¿Cómo realizar estimación de regresiones en un for en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo la siguiente base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito estimar regresiones de la siguiente forma:

```
ir_total = b0 + b1 9dejulio + b2 Azul + b3 Bolivar
ir_total = b0 + b1 9dejulio + b2 Azul + b3 CoronelSuarez
.
.
.
.
ir_total = b0 + b1 pehuajo + b2 Dolores + b3 Junin
```

Es decir, necesito estimar regresiones con la variable y=ir_total, 3 regresores que serán pasar por todos los distintos departamentos. Finalmente imprimir en un DataFrame o tabla los coeficientes y el R^2 de cada regresión

Estoy intentando algo como lo siguiente

```
n=ncol(data)

for (i in 3:n) {
    model = lm (data = data, formula = data[,2] ~ data[,i] + data [,i+1] + data[,i+2])

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, genero sinteticamente un set de datos similar al que muestras:

```
set.seed(2022)
df <- data.frame(year=sample(2001:2018, 10, replace=TRUE),
                 ir_total=runif(10),
                 Azul=runif(10),
                 Bolivar=runif(10),
                 Dolores=runif(10),
                 Junin=runif(10)
                 )
```

El primer problema, es generar todas las combinaciones de 3 variables independientes, para esto seleccionamos los nombre de columna que van a participar del cálculo, en tu caso, todas menos las dos primeras y luego simplemente con `combn()` generamos las combinaciones:

```
independientes <- colnames(df[, c(-1,-2)])
combinaciones <- apply(combn(independientes, m=3), 2, 
                       FUN=function(x){paste0("`", x, "`", collapse = ' + ')})
combinaciones
    
[1] "Azul + Bolivar + Dolores"  "Azul + Bolivar + Junin"   
[3] "Azul + Dolores + Junin"    "Bolivar + Dolores + Junin"
```

Terminamos con cadenas parciales, pero nos falta completar la formula y convertirlas realmente en una formula:

```
combinaciones <- sapply(paste("ir_total ~", combinaciones), as.formula)
```

Tenemos ahora una lista de formulas, simplemente con `lapply()` aplicamos `lm` a cada elemento:

```
lapply(combinaciones, lm, df)
```

Por último, teniendo una lista con todos los modelos, es relativamente sencillo "extraer" los datos que mencionas

```
lapply(modelos, FUN=function(x) {cbind(r2=summary(x)$r.squared,
                                       coef1=coef(x)[2],
                                       coef2=coef(x)[3],
                                       coef3=coef(x)[4]
                                       )}) -> datos

datos <- do.call(rbind, datos)
rownames(datos) <- NULL

datos

             r2      coef1       coef2      coef3
[1,] 0.18734057  0.2333279 -0.50774617  0.0534951
[2,] 0.23616736  0.1888734 -0.74079657 -0.3212276
[3,] 0.02565005  0.1438587  0.07310115  0.1276001
[4,] 0.20258716 -0.7262850 -0.08811687 -0.4056673
```

Comment: Cuando corre ```combinaciones <- sapply(paste("ir_total ~", combinaciones), as.formula)```  imprime el siguiente error: ```Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:14: unexpected symbol
1: ir_total ~ 9 de^```

Comment: Si, el problema de tener nombres de columna sin normalizar, en tu caso son los municipios con espacio en el medio. Simplemente hay que agregar backtick al construir la formula, ahí edite mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias! pude correr correctamente el script. ¿ Cómo se podría indexar cada regresión con los nombres de los municipios?

Comment: La lista de los modelos ya está indexada con el nombre de la formula, por ej: `ir_total ~ Azul + Bolivar + Dolores`, ¿qué es lo que quisieras?

Comment: Me gustaría reportar las 10 regresiones con en el r2 más alto con el nombre de cada variable x utilizada.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás esta es una opción para abordar esta pregunta. Es probable que no sea la más eficiente, pero te podría ayudar. Considerando que no existe una muestra de la data, acá te dejo un ejemplo con data ficticia:

```
set.seed(123)                         
y <- rnorm(1000)
x1 <- rnorm(1000) + 0.123 * y
x2 <- rnorm(1000) + 0.123 * x1 + 0.456 * y
x3 <- rnorm(1000) - 0.123 * x1 + 0.456 * x2 - 0.789 * y
data <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)

# Crear una lista vacía  
modelos_resultados <- list()                 

# Crear for-loop
for(i in 2:ncol(data)) {                 
  
  predictores_i <- colnames(data)[2:i]    # Crear vector con las variables x
  modelos_resultados [[i - 1]] <- summary(     # Guardar resultados de cada modelo en la lista
    lm(y ~ ., data[ , c("y", predictores_i )]))
  
}

# Extraer los resultados de los modelos en formato tidy
resultados_tidy <- purrr::map(modelos_resultados, broom::tidy) |> 
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id="predvar") |> 
  filter(predvar  %in% c(1:3)) # Filtrar por el número de modelos que necesitas, en este caso, considera los primeros tres modelos. 

# Extraer r^2 de cada modelo
r.squared <- map_dfr(modelos_resultados, ~ glance(.x) |> 
                       select(r.squared)) |> mutate(Modelo_ID = as.character(1:3))

# Agregar r^2 al resto de las variables de cada modelo.  
resultados_tidy <- resultados_tidy |> 
left_join(r.squared, by = c("predvar" = "Modelo_ID")) |> 
  select(predvar, everything())
```

**DATAFRAME**

```
               y           x1            x2          x3
1   -0.560475647 -1.064737229 -0.8981432962  0.01331714
2   -0.230177489 -1.068266875  0.0005801183 -0.01448573
3    1.558708314  0.173740882  0.1905519481 -2.61246459
4    0.070508391 -0.123502601  1.2361886536 -0.17402286
5    0.129287735 -2.533440383 -0.0785220848  2.77228931
6    1.715064987  1.251526449  0.3207390712 -1.39828203
7    0.460916206  0.306418429 -1.5590257073 -0.19877619
8   -1.265061235  2.260604841 -0.9424946334  0.10577487
9   -0.686852852  0.600715337  1.8067019382  1.90171929
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  predvar term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value r.squared
  <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 1       (Intercept)  0.00739    0.0307     0.240 8.10e- 1    0.0415
2 1       x1           0.197      0.0299     6.57  7.93e-11    0.0415
3 2       (Intercept)  0.0138     0.0283     0.487 6.27e- 1    0.190 
4 2       x1           0.112      0.0282     3.97  7.60e- 5    0.190 
5 2       x2           0.359      0.0266    13.5   2.37e-38    0.190 
6 3       (Intercept)  0.00563    0.0228     0.247 8.05e- 1    0.473 
7 3       x1           0.0140     0.0232     0.604 5.46e- 1    0.473 
8 3       x2           0.452      0.0218    20.7   1.96e-79    0.473 
9 3       x3          -0.429      0.0186   -23.1   6.80e-95    0.473
```